# C# and PHP show two different results for a calculation with the same code logic

Tags: c#, php, logic

I have two sets of code one in PHP that i'm trying to get to work and one in C# both show slightly different values.

Below is the C# example:

```
decimal dayrate = l.dRate * balance / 36500;
Console.WriteLine("dayrate: {0}", dayrate); //dayrate output = 0.0582191780821917808219178082
```

The PHP example:

```
$dayrate = $row['dRate'] * $balance / 36500; 
echo "Dayrate: $dayrate"; //dayrate output = 0.058219178082192
```

Why is this and can it be corrected in the PHP example.

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into precision problems.

- The C# decimal class is a 128-bit decimal value accurate to around 28 decimal places.
- PHPs FLOAT class is a 64-bit decimal value accurate to around 15 decimal places.

You can fix this by using arbitrarily sized decimals in PHP:

[BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)

Or by using the `double` class in C#, which matches the PHP Float class.

If you need the values to match exactly, there isn't a whole lot you can do if you're problem uses irrational numbers. You should look at your programs requirement and decide on what precision is required, then round or truncate values to that precision.

Answer (score 1):

It is basicaly for datatype. In C# use decimal for long numbers, that for the result is most exactly. In php you must use Float Datatype for it.